# Am I closing this function correctly?

Tags: go

I keep getting an error after a few hours that I have too many open files.

I have already edited the `ulimit -n` but that only seems to prolong the time before the error occurs and crashes the process.

I believe I have narrowed it down to this function, I just am not sure if I am closing it right.

I currently have a function

```
go func() {
    if _, err := io.Copy(rw, stdout); err != nil {
        if !WritePipeBroken.MatchString(err.Error()) &&
            !ConnectionResetByPeer.MatchString(err.Error()) {
            rollbar.Error(rollbar.ERR, err)
        }
        log.Printf("pipeThruFfmpegToMp3: %v\n", err)
        if err := ffmpeg.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("pipeThruFfmpegToMp3: %v\n", err)
        }
    }
    rw.Flush()
    wg.Done()
}()
```

I believe that it is hanging, so should I do this instead

```
go func() {
    if _, err := io.Copy(rw, stdout); err != nil {
        if !WritePipeBroken.MatchString(err.Error()) &&
            !ConnectionResetByPeer.MatchString(err.Error()) {
            rollbar.Error(rollbar.ERR, err)
        }
        log.Printf("pipeThruFfmpegToMp3: %v\n", err)
        if err := ffmpeg.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("pipeThruFfmpegToMp3: %v\n", err)
        }
    }
    if ffmpeg.Process != nil {
        ffmpeg.Process.Kill()
    }
    if stdout != nil {
        stdin.Close()
    }
    rw.Flush()
    wg.Done()
}()
```

Comment: What is the `rw` variable? Also, `Copy` function has two arguments - destination and source. You're using `stdout` as a source which is obviously wrong.

Comment: rw is is ```rw web.ResponseWriter```, and in this case not sure using ```stdout``` is wrong as I am piping the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `defer` statement like google [advises](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover):

```
func CopyFile(dstName, srcName string) (written int64, err error) {
    src, err := os.Open(srcName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer src.Close()

    dst, err := os.Create(dstName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer dst.Close()

    return io.Copy(dst, src)
}
```

Comment: using defer in this use case has a higher overhead, so not sure that it would be the right use case to just use defer.

Comment: @nadermx what overhead are you referring to? The there's no reason to make a function this slow more complicated just to save a few nanoseconds. This is exactly the case where you should use defer.